# objective c gets EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on completionhandler

Tags: objective-c

i'm new to objective-c, please bear with me if i ask stupid questions :) 
The following is part of code i have to start vpn tunnel, but keeps getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

```
- (void)startTunnelWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)options completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL * error))completionHandler {

    vpnAdapter = [[OpenAdapter alloc] init];
    vpnAdapter.delegate = self;

    // get config

    config = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];

    NETunnelProviderProtocol *protocol = (NETunnelProviderProtocol *)self.protocolConfiguration;
    config = protocol.providerConfiguration;

    host = config[@"server"];

    // Load config data
    username = config[@"username"];
    password = config[@"password"];


    if(option != nil){
        [vpnAdapter connect:host user:username pass:password add:YES completionHandler:^(BOOL success){
           // return success;
            completionHandler(&success); // Thread 2: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xbcc68f020)
        }];

    }else{
        [vpnAdapter connect:host user:username pass:password add:NO completionHandler:^(BOOL success){

            completionHandler(&success);

        }];
    } 
}
```

here is connect method

```
- (void)connect: (NSString *) host user:(NSString *)username pass:(NSString *) password add:(Boolean) isAdd completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL success)) completionHandler{

    dispatch_queue_attr_t attributes = dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qos_class(DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL, QOS_CLASS_UTILITY, 0);
    dispatch_queue_t connectQueue = dispatch_queue_create("me.ss-abramchuk.open-adapter.connection", attributes);
    dispatch_async(connectQueue, ^{
        // Call connect
        //int ret=1;
        NSArray* options = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            @"--user", username,
                            host,
                            nil];

        if(isAdd){
            options = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       @"--user", username,
                       @"--protocol", @"ad",
                       host,
                       nil];
        }
        //NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
        (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        //NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSMutableArray *arguments = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1+[options count]];
        [arguments addObject:@"connect"];
        [arguments addObjectsFromArray:options];

        int argc = [arguments count];
        char **argv = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*) * (argc + 1));

        [arguments enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *option, NSUInteger i, BOOL *stop) {
            const char * c_string = [option UTF8String];
            int length = (int)strlen(c_string);
            char *c_string_copy = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (length + 1));
            strcpy(c_string_copy, c_string);
            argv[i] = c_string_copy;
        }];
        argv[argc] = NULL;
        const char *cfPass=[password UTF8String];
        int ret = self.vpnClient->start2connect(argc, argv, cfPass);
        BOOL result;
        if (ret!=0){
            result=false;
        }
        else {result = true;}
        completionHandler(result);
    }); 
}
```

all of these are from networkextension and while debugging, i found `int ret = self.vpnClient->start2connect(argc, argv, cfPass);`
seems not returning any value.

however, i confirmed that the ***start2connect*** method does return int value 
so for now, anyone can help explain what's wrong?

thanks

Comment: Why is the parameter to the block parameter for `startTunnelWithOptions` using `BOOL *`? Why not just make it’s parameter a `BOOL`, too? Then you’d just do `completionHandler(success);` and you’re done. I don’t understand what you’re trying to do...

Comment: can you be more specific?  thanks

Comment: By the way, when you get this running, I’d suggest you run this through the Leaks tool in Instruments, because all of these `malloc` calls without corresponding `free` calls must be causing leaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BOOL *` is a pointer to a `BOOL`. We don’t use that pattern very often.  We use it where the block needs to update a `BOOL` property somewhere, e.g. in [`enumerateMatchesinString`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression/1409687-enumeratematchesinstring?language=objc), where you can update the boolean that `stop` points to in order to stop the enumeration.

But this is a completion handler, so there’s no point in passing a pointer to the boolean (one that presumably was on the stack, inviting problems). Just pass the boolean itself, not a pointer to it.

I would suggest that instead of:

```
- (void)startTunnelWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)options completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL * error))completionHandler {
    ...
    [vpnAdapter connect:host user:username pass:password add:YES completionHandler:^(BOOL success){
        completionHandler(&success);
    }];
    ...
}
```

That you want:

```
- (void)startTunnelWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)options completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL success))completionHandler {
    ...
    [vpnAdapter connect:host user:username pass:password add:YES completionHandler:^(BOOL success){
        completionHandler(success);
    }];
    ...
}
```

Note the block parameter isn’t `BOOL * error` but rather `BOOL success` and when it calls the `completionHandler`, there’s not `&` before `success`.

If there’s some reason you needed to update the `BOOL`, then that’s a different matter, but it doesn’t make sense in the context of a completion handler.